# Create conditional Join in LINQ with constant

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a sql server query which goes something like this:

```sql
select p.*
from 
  parcel p
inner join 
  jurisdiction j
  on (j.unit_type = 'RM' and j.grp_code = right(p.jurisdiction,3)) or 
  (j.jurisdiction_code = p.jurisdiction)
```

Basically, if the unit_type is 'RM', grab every jurisdiction ending with the same 3 characters.  If the unit_type is not 'RM', match up the jurisdictions.

I'm trying to create an equivalent vb.net linq query expression.  Here's my attempt:

```sql
From p in db.parcel
Join j in db.jurisdiction
  On p.jurisdiction.substring(p.jurisdiction.length-3,3) Equals h.grp_code
  And j.unit_type Equals "RM" 
  OR p.jurisdiction Equals j.jurisdiction
```

The above query doesn't work because of the j.unit_type Equals "RM".  I get an error saying I must use a range variable on both sides of the equation (which just won't work for a constant).

I'm also unsure of precedence with regard to the order linq will resolve the and/or combinations (since I can't seem to use parentheses to group the conditions I want together), and haven't been able to find anything about linq query precedence via google.

Comment: Actually it doesn't matter. LINQ supports only equijoins. Use `Where` instead.

Comment: I hadn't realized LINQ only supports equijoins.  I ended up creating a crossjoin and then filtering via the where clause.

Thanks for the help!